# Sublime text 3 (Latex): How to organise raw data to be inserted in a table?

Tags: tables, sublime-text

I have been working on this idea for some time and I thought of sharing this information. Suppose you have some raw data as so

```
0.7483 0.5526 0.2311 0.1460
0.8346 0.5804 0.2164 0.1100
0.8430 0.5676 0.2089 0.0711
```

And as you may see this is not suitable to be inserted in a latex table. Is there a way to organise this dataset such that it has $ and & sign between them such that I do not have to regularly pass through them.

Comment: I think that reducing the scope of the question to `sublime` is not needed...

Answer (score 2):

No need to add anything. You can use [`pgfplotstable`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[sci zerofill]{
a b c d
0.7483 0.5526 0.2311 0.1460
0.8346 0.5804 0.2164 0.1100
0.8430 0.5676 0.2089 0.0711
}
```

[image: formatted table]

...you have zillions of options, just check the docs. For example, a quick change:

```
...
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule},
    fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=4,
]{
...
```

Gives:

[image: new table]

without touching anything else. In general, I prefer to use the numbers as they are generated by the application that generates them, so that if I had to change them, it's just a copy and paste (or, better, an included file with the data, you can do it with `pgfplotstable`). Keeping content and format separate is the main reason to use LaTeX...

Comment: Thank you for this but this is in Scientific notations. Sometimes one needs to avoid this see the 7.11.10^-2.

Comment: @rsc05 you have plenty of options to control how numbers are formatted when using pgtplotstable.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer to this question and thought about sharing it with you. This involves using regular expression

Step 1: `Ctr+h`, then `Alt+R`

Step 2: Change the first number in each line (as it has a different formation) as

```
Find: ^(\d+.?\d+)
Replace: \$$1\$ \&
```

Then press on `Ctrl+Alt+Enter`

Step 3: Then I followed the suggestions of this useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between), I did the following step to insert a $ sign on all numbers except those that has already $ sign or those numbers at the very end of the line.

```
Find: (\$\d+.?\d+\$|\d+.?\d+$)(*SKIP)(*F)|(\d+.?\d+)
Replace: \$$2\$ \&
```

Then press on `Ctrl+Alt+Enter`

Step 4: The only thing that is left is to replace all numbers except those that have already a dollar sign as

```
Find: \$\d+.?\d+\$(*SKIP)(*F)|(\d+.?\d+)
Replace: \$$1\$
```

Then press on `Ctrl+Alt+Enter`

Where this step finds all numbers except those that were already wrapped by a $ sign.